function to randomly select an image from an array of shapes and displaying the sides number on the correct side,
I want to create an array of images for the shapes and when displayed I want the side number to be displayed on the correct side and the cm to change to m and also for them to be together
I tried to generate the shapes automatically but also I wanted the shapes to be irregular and regular. here is the code.


function generateRandomShape() {
  var containerWidth = 200;
  var containerHeight = 200;
  var sides = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 3; // Generate a random number between 3 and 6
  var svg = `<svg width="${containerWidth}" height="${containerHeight}" viewBox="0 0 ${containerWidth} ${containerHeight}" class="shape">`;
  var centerX = containerWidth / 2;
  var centerY = containerHeight / 2;
  var radius = Math.min(containerWidth, containerHeight) * 0.4; // Ensure shape fits inside container
  var angle = (Math.PI * 2) / sides;

  var points = "";
  var sideLengths = [];
  var perimeter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
    // Generate random side lengths ranging from 1 to 30
    var length = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
    sideLengths.push(length);
    perimeter += length;

    // Calculate vertex position
    var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(i * angle);
    var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(i * angle);
    points += x + "," + y + " ";

    // Calculate position for side number
    var sideAngle = (i * angle + (i + 1) * angle) / 2; // Angle bisector
    var sideX = centerX + (radius + 5) * Math.cos(sideAngle); // Place number slightly outside the shape
    var sideY = centerY + (radius + 5) * Math.sin(sideAngle); // Place number slightly outside the shape
    svg += `<text x="${sideX}" y="${sideY}" class="side-number">${length} cm</text>`;
  }

  svg += `<polygon points="${points}"></polygon>`;
  svg += `</svg>`;

  document.getElementById("shape-container").innerHTML = svg;
  console.log("Side lengths:", sideLengths);
  console.log("Perimeter:", perimeter);
}
.shape-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.shape {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.side-number {
  font-size: 10px;
}
<body onload="generateRandomShape()">
  <div class="shape-container" id="shape-container"></div>
</body>




You need to refactor your code accordingly shapes to be irregular and regular like below.
Refer the code below for reference:


function generateRandomShape() {
  var containerWidth = 200;
  var containerHeight = 200;
  var sides = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 3;
  var svg = `<svg width="${containerWidth}" height="${containerHeight}" viewBox="0 0 ${containerWidth} ${containerHeight}" class="shape">`;
  var centerX = containerWidth / 2;
  var centerY = containerHeight / 2;
  var radius = Math.min(containerWidth, containerHeight) * 0.4;
  var angle = (Math.PI * 2) / sides;

  var points = "";
  var sideLengths = [];
  var perimeter = 0;
  var prevX = centerX + radius;
  var prevY = centerY;

  for (var i = 0; i < sides; i++) {

    var lengthCm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
    var lengthM = lengthCm / 100;
    sideLengths.push(lengthM);
    perimeter += lengthM;

    var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(i * angle);
    var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(i * angle);
    points += x + "," + y + " ";

    var sideMidX = (prevX + x) / 2;
    var sideMidY = (prevY + y) / 2;

    svg += `<text x="${sideMidX}" y="${sideMidY}" class="side-number">${lengthM.toFixed(2)} m</text>`;

    prevX = x;
    prevY = y;
  }

  svg += `<polygon points="${points}"></polygon>`;
  svg += `</svg>`;

  document.getElementById("shape-container").innerHTML = svg;
  console.log("Side lengths:", JSON.stringify(sideLengths));
  console.log("Perimeter:", JSON.stringify(perimeter));
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", generateRandomShape);
.shape-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.shape {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.side-number {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="shape-container" id="shape-container"></div> 
</body>
</html>



